# Require SSL connection for checkout and order tags problem

Tags: expresso-store

EE v2.4

Store v1.6.1

Toggling the "Require SSL connection for checkout and order tags" setting doesn't do anything. There are Checkout Tags, but those pages do not get redirected to HTTPS. I can manually enter the URL with the HTTPS protocol without issue.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you upgrade to the latest version of Store to see if that fixes your issues.

Comment: What is your hosting setup like? Apache or IIS? Are you running a load balancer or reverse proxy which might affect the HTTPS detection? Have you edited any core Store files?

Comment: Apache server, no load balancer, no reverse proxy, Media Temple dv hosting. This is a project I've inherited, but I don't believe any core files have been edited. I've just been given a copy of v1.6.3, so I'll upgrade and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Have you managed to get this resolved yet?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the way folks code to determine whether HTTPs is on or not is not according to the PHP docs which is maybe what you are running into. I've [fixed this HTTPS issue with Mo_variables](https://github.com/eedfwChris/mo_variables/commit/bae1142ff3b30f8bd216c67c5f1c8bb135c6736e) which is why I am mildly seasoned with knowledge about it:

An alternative solution is one I use that involves using two plugins by rsanchez.

1. [Mo_variables](https://github.com/rsanchez/mo_variables) (be sure to update as I made a pull request adding some variables)
2. [Http_header](https://github.com/rsanchez/http_header)

With those two installed you can then do the following at the top of you template (you can do the opposite too on nonsecure templates):

```
{if not_secure}{exp:http_header location="{secure_site_url}{uri_string}" status="301"}{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can quite often be something happening on the server/network level that you don't specifically know about. I had a similar problem and I eventually discovered that it was due to some reverse proxying being done on the server that I wasn't aware of. It could be worth confirming with the hosts. I wouldn't be surprised if MT were doing something similar.

Failing that a solid solution is to use [DM Force SSL](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dm-force-ssl). It's a very useful plugin and just ensures that page is served up over SSL. No harm in being sure either way. You simple place:

```
{exp:dm_force_ssl:force}
```

At the top of the template and it will always redirect.