# Using login_form tag with https

Tags: members, login

Using the [login_form tag](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/member/index.html#login-form-tag), is there a way to specify a secure return address, without entering a full domain name? Only the 'intranet' part of the site should be under https.

For example, I can do this:

```
{exp:member:login_form return="https://www.mywebsite.com/intranet/"}
```

But I can't do something like this:

```
{exp:member:login_form return="intranet/index" secure="yes"}
```

With the first method, it seems a bit naff how you see a 'You are now logged in' page that's http rather than https after logging in. Also, using a full domain name doesn't play nicely with version control and multi-server environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your login form page https? Seems like return="" would keep you on the same protocol with a relative path if your originating form was over https.

You could use a redirect as I described in [this thread regarding requiring SSL](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/6865/require-ssl-connection-for-checkout-and-order-tags-problem/7208#7208) which would also prevent users from accidentally ending up on http:// as well. Though it'd be unfortunate if you had to do a redirect and I wonder if it opens you up to some sort of session hijacking.